# why designer is showing a form instead of a datamodule in my TService inherited class?

Tags: delphi

I declare this :

```
Unit BaseGuardian

TBaseGuardianService = class(TService)
public
end;
```

i don't define any `dfm` with this definition. Later I do :

```
unit Guardian

TGuardianService = class(TBaseGuardianService )
public
end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
```

and the code of the dfm :

```
object GuardianService: TGuardianService
  DisplayName = 'GuardianService'
end
```

but the problem when i close the project and reopen it delphi show me the service (datamodule) like a **TForm** ! (so first error saying no property `DisplayName` and then later i see a form in the designer). What i missed ?

---

this is the content of the dpr file:

```
program Guardian;

uses
  Vcl.SvcMgr,
  System.SysUtils,
  Guardian in 'Guardian.pas' {GuardianService: TService},
  BaseGuardian in 'BaseGuardian.pas' {BaseGuardianService: TService};

{$R *.RES}

begin

  if not Application.DelayInitialize or Application.Installing then
    Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TGuardianService, GuardianService);
  Application.Run;

end.
```

Comment: What is in the dpr file?

Comment: thanks @DavidHeffernan, i just updated the question with the content of my service and the dpr file

Comment: This was a data module before. Now it's a service. What on earth?

Comment: yes but a service is a datamodule IE: TService = class(TDataModule) ... i start to write sample with datamodule to make think simple, seam it's not so i prefer finally to write my full source code

Comment: Data module inheritance is like forms. Remove your TGuardianService  from the project. Then "File" "New" "Other" "Inheritable Items" and select TBaseGuardianService.

Comment: I already try, it's didn't work i have a error BaseGuardianService not found and the dfm is not created (but the unit yes)

Comment: I don't know what you're doing wrong but I can tell it works.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: but in TBaseGuardianService do you have a dfm? because me i don't have (and don't want) a dfm in this class! with dfm yes it's work (but with dfm defined in the base class i have another bug, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905523/why-designer-is-showing-a-form-instead-of-a-datamodule-in-my-tservice-inherited)

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: mistake in the previous link, good one is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909299/why-property-oldcreateorder-is-continuously-getting-back-to-true

Comment: Yes, I tested with a dfm.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz ... so I will stay with dfm maybe more easy :) do you also have this bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49909299/why-property-oldcreateorder-is-continuously-getting-back-to-true

Comment: If you don't want a dfm use CreateNew, read help. Yes, OnCreateOrder is always true in the inherited module. However there is no restriction for the base class. Looks like a bug to me.