# Why property OldCreateOrder is continuously getting back to true?

Tags: delphi

I declare this :

```
Unit BaseGuardian

TBaseGuardianService = class(TService)
public
end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
```

and the code of the dfm :

```
object BaseGuardianService: TBaseGuardianService
  OldCreateOrder = False
  DisplayName = 'BaseGuardian'
end
```

then later i define this class :

```
unit Guardian
TGuardianService = class(TBaseGuardianService )
public
end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
```

and the code of the dfm :

```
inherited GuardianService: TGuardianService
  DisplayName = 'Guardian'
end
```

and anytime i open the unit Guardian.pas i see that `OldCreateOrder` is set to true, and no matter what i do, set to false, save close the unit and reopen it i always see it back again to true :(

Is it a bug? what can i do ?

I can see this in the code source of delphi

```
procedure TDataModule.ReadState(Reader: TReader);
begin
  FOldCreateOrder := not ModuleIsCPP;
  inherited ReadState(Reader);
end;
```

don't know what it's mean ...

Comment: `OldCreateOrder` is False by default, so `OldCreateOrder = False` doesn't belong in your DFM to begin with. But in any case, it makes sense why `OldCreateOrder` is getting set to True - [`ModuleIsCPP` is True only in C++ and is False in Delphi](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/delphi-in-a/1565926595/re179.html), so `not ModuleIsCPP` is True in your case.  `ReadState()` is called during DFM streaming.

Comment: @Remy - ReadState is called after setting FOldCreateOrder. So "not ModuleIsCPP" should be overriden if OnCreateOrder is streamed while writing. Besides there's no restriction for the base module, it's default is even false.

Comment: There's a report for this here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20016

Comment: It's been like this since Delphi 6.

Comment: @DaveNottage ... ooh thanks ! so it's a bug :( i guess I will need to leave with it as it's seam their is no way around :(

Comment: @RemyLebeau `OldCreateOrder` is (was, as it changed in Delphi 11) **True** by default, this is because code from Delphi <= 3 didn't have it, but behaved like on Delphi > 3 with `OldCreateOrder = True` (hence the prefix Old...), so any form opened in Delphi > 3 that doesn't contain an explicit value has to be considered True for backwards compatibility. Embarcadero **broke backwards compatibility with Delphi 11**, in which OldCreateOrder was removed and hardcoded to False (I just ran into this while testing code that worked fine 'til Delphi 10.4 and in Delphi 11/12 doesn't work anymore).